# How do I use an image as an epigraph?

Tags: formatting

There is a "picture that paints a thousand words" that I would like to use in the frontmatter of a book, similar to an epigraph. What is the proper way to lay out the page? Should it have a title? Caption? Examples would be helpful here. The only one that comes to mind is when fantasy authors put maps at the front of their books. But this would be a photograph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many older books used to have an illustration facing the title page. This is called a frontispiece. Examples can be found in the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_frontispiece).

Frontispieces could be decorative (e.g. ornaments) or informative (e.g. an image of the author or an illustration relevant to the book's content). Of course this image can also be epigraphic in nature.

The frontispiece doesn't have a heading, but it can contain text as part of the illustration and it can be explained by a [caption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caption_(text)) below the image.

The [front matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Front_matter) of a book is ordered in a certain way by tradition: half title, frontispiece, title, copyright page, dedication, epigraph, table of contents, foreword, preface, acknowledgements, introduction, prologue, main text, bibliography, index. This order is what feels natural and comfortable to readers. If you follow this convention, your readers know where they are in the book and which way they need to go and how far if they want to get somewhere else. I wouldn't deviate from this unless it was for a good reason.